# Verifying $\sum_{n\leq x, (n, k) = 1} \frac{1}{n} = \frac{\phi(k)}{k}\log x + O(1)$.

Tags: number-theory, solution-verification

I am not able to find this problem on Math.SE before, and I also want to make sure my solution is correct. Can someone help look over it?

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{n\leq x, (n, k) = 1} \frac{1}{n} &= \sum_{n\leq x} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{d\mid n, d\mid k}\mu(d) \\ &= \sum_{d\mid k}\mu(d)\sum_{d\mid n,n\leq x}\frac{1}{n}\\&=\sum_{d\mid k}\frac{\mu(d)}{d}\sum_{n\leq\frac{x}{d}}\frac{1}{n}\\&=\sum_{d\mid k}\frac{\mu(d)}{d}\left(\log\left(\frac{x}{d}\right) + O(1)\right) \\ &= \sum_{d\mid k}\frac{\mu(d)}{d}(\log x + O(\log d) + O(1)) \\ &= \log x\cdot\sum_{d\mid k}\frac{\mu(d)}{d} + {\color{red}{O\left(\sum_{d\mid k}\frac{\mu(d)\log d}{d}\right)}} + O\left(\sum_{d\mid k}\frac{\mu(d)}{d}\right) \\ &= \log  x\cdot\prod_{p\mid k}\left(1 - \frac{1}{p}\right) + O(1) \\ &= \frac{\phi(k)}{k}\log x + O(1)
\end{align*}$$

In particular, I simplified the red term as follows:

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{d\mid k}\frac{\mu(d)\log d}{d} \ll \sum_{d\mid k}\frac{\mu(d)}{d^{\frac{1}{2}}} = \prod_{p\mid k}\left(1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{p}}\right) \ll 1
\end{align*}$$

Since each term in the product is negative. Is this correct? And how can the red term be simplified simpler? The method I used seems kind of indirect and I imagine there are better ways to prove the result.

Thank you!

Comment: Seems fine to me... Btw, can you tell the name of the book??

Comment: The term in red is just a constant dependent on the fixed $k,$ there is no $x$ in it. Also each factor in the product is positive and be aware that $\mu(d)$ might be negative.

Comment: It seems in your simplification you use asymptotics for $k$ large, but it is fixed.

Comment: @F_M_ oh, instead of negative i meant its <1, so the product is bounded by 1? In particular that means i dont need to assume k is large(?)

Comment: And also, $\ll$ means big-O notation here, not significantly less than. See Vinogradov notation

Comment: Indeed, in fact you don't have to assume anything on $k$, it is fixed. In particular $\sum_{d|k} \mu(d)\log(d)d^{-1}$ is a constant (depending on $k$), so there is no reason to go to the product, since the sum gives you a hard constant which can be absorbed in the $O(1)$ term. Also be aware that when you use $\ll$ you need to put absolute values.

Comment: @F_M_ Ohh I see what you mean now. I guess my proof will give a stronger result of $\cdots \leq \frac{\phi(k)}{k}\log x + 2$?

Comment: @rahul "An Invitation to Modern Number Theory" by Steven J. Miller and Ramin Takloo-Bighash, exercise 2.2.24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get a smaller $O$-bound, one can use the formula
$$
\sum_{n\leq x} \frac{1}{n} = \log(x) + C + O\left(\frac{1}{x}\right),
$$
where $C = \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\left(1+ \frac12 + \dots \frac1n - \log(n) \right) $ is the Euler constant. This approach gives

\begin{align*}
\sum_{\substack{n\leq x \\ (n,k)=1}} \frac{1}{n} & = \sum_{d|k } \frac{\mu(d)}{d} \sum_{n\leq \frac{x}{d}} \frac{1}{n} \\ 
& =\sum_{d|k} \frac{\mu(d)}{d} \left(\log \frac{x}{d} + C + O\left(\frac{d}{x}\right)\right)\\
 &= \sum_{d|k} \frac{\mu(d)}{d} \left(\log x +C\right) \underbrace{- \sum_{d|k} \mu(d) \frac{\log(d)}{d}}_{:= C_k} + O\left(\frac{2^{\omega(k)}}{x}\right) \\ 
&= \frac{\varphi(k)}{k} \left(\log x + C\right) + C_k + O\left(\frac{2^{\omega(k)}}{x}\right).
\end{align*}
Here $C_k$ is just a specific constant, depending on $k.$

This result is more precise since it has a $O_k(1/x)$ bound rather than a $O(1)$ bound.

In your simplification of the red term, be aware that

$$
\sum_{n\leq x} f(n) \ll \sum_{n \leq x} |f(n)|,
$$

so you need extra absolute values.

I hope this helps.

Comment: The first equality is not correct since $\log d$ is not multiplicative.

Comment: You got me, indeed, I'll make an edit.

Comment: This is clearly the right way to go; however note that the $O(\frac1x)$ term should actually be $O(\frac{2^{\omega(k)}}x)$ because of the sum over $d$. Also I would remove the first paragraph since it's contradicted by the (correct) last few lines.

Comment: Thanks for the helpfull comment!

Comment: I see, this is helpful. For $O_k$ I assume it means fixing $k$? Also in my original post, I (believe I) proved $C_k \leq 1$ too :)

Comment: @GregMartin since you’re summing $\mu$ over divisors, shouldn’t it always be $0$? (Well 1 if k=1)

Answer (score 1):

None of the big-$O$ terms should have $\mu(d)$ in them: When writing a term as part of a big-$O$ expression, all sign information/cancellation is lost. Therefore the error produced by this method is
$\displaystyle\sum_{d\mid k} \frac{\log d}d$, which can be larger than any power of $\log k$.

Comment: Hey, I don’t understand what you mean. So you are saying that the error term is instead $\ll \sum_{d\mid k} \frac{\log d}{d}$ which can be unbounded if we take $k$ over all integers? However, the $\mu(d)$ in the summand should make it bounded (by $1$), as shown in my post right? So not sure what you’re implying by this answer haha any clarification would be great

Comment: The notation $O(g(x))$ describes an unspecified function $f(x)$ such that $|f(x)|\le  Cg(x)$ for some constant $C$. Note the absolute value signs around $f(x)$ in this definition. Consequently, $g(x)$ must be a nonnegative function for the notation to make sense: $O(-1)$ is meaningless. It also follows that it's not the case that $f(x) = O(f(x))$ for all functions—only that $f(x) = O(|f(x)|)$. In particular, $\mu(d)$ is not $O(\mu(d))$ (that notation is meaningless) but only $O(|\mu(d)|)$, which for practical purposes we might as well write as $O(1)$.

Comment: (continued) When passing to $O$-notation in error terms, we are deliberately (for the sake of simplicity in future manipulations) throwing away information such as sign. If we only know that two error terms are at most $1$ in absolute value, then the cumulative effect of those two error terms is at most $2$ in absolute value, and there's nothing more we can say.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is dedicated to evaluate the $C_k$ explicitly so that we can get a grasp about its growth behavior:

\begin{aligned}
-C_k=\sum_{d|k}{\mu(d)\log d\over d}
&=\sum_{\substack{d|k\\d\text{ squarefree}}}{\mu(d)\over d}\sum_{p|d}\log p \\
&=\sum_{p|k}\log p\sum_{\substack{d|k\\p|d}}{\mu(d)\over d}=\sum_{p|k}\log p\sum_{\substack{t|k\\p\nmid t}}{\mu(pd)\over pd} \\
&=-\sum_{p|k}{\log p\over p}\sum_{\substack{t|k\\p\nmid t}}{\mu(t)\over t}=-\sum_{p|k}{\log p\over p}\prod_{p'|k,p'\ne p}\left(1-{1\over p'}\right) \\
&=-{\varphi(k)\over k}\sum_{p|k}{\log p\over p(1-p^{-1}}=-{\varphi(k)\over k}\sum_{p|k}{\log p\over p-1}.
\end{aligned}

Therefore, for any $1\le T\le k$ there is

\begin{aligned}
|C_k|
&\le\sum_{p|k}{\log p\over p-1}\le\sum_{p\le T}{\log p\over p-1}+{1\over T-1}\sum_{p|k}\log p \\
&\le\sum_{p\le T}{\log p\over p-1}+{\log k\over T-1}\ll\log T+{\log k\over T}
\end{aligned}

Setting $T=\log3k$ gives $C_k=O(\log\log3k)$, so we have

\begin{aligned}
\sum_{\substack{n\le x\\(n,k)=1}}\frac1n
&=\sum_{d|k}{\mu(d)\over d}(\log x+O(1))+C_k \\
&={\varphi(k)\over k}\log x+C_k+O\left(\prod_{p|k}\left(1+\frac1p\right)\right) \\
&={\varphi(k)\over k}\log x+O(\log\log3k)+\color{blue}{O\left(\exp\left(1+\sum_{p|k}\frac1p\right)\right)} \\
&={\varphi(k)\over k}\log x+O(\log\log3k)
\end{aligned}

For the blue part, it suffices to notice that

$$
\sum_{p|k}\frac1p\ll\sum_{p\le\log3k}\frac1p+\sum_{p|k}{\log p\over\log3k}\ll\log\log\log3k.
$$